# @angular/core"' has no exported member '__core_private__'

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I am working with Angular 2 in Visual Studio & MVC
My project worked until this morning. Dont know whats causing this but nothing has changed in the code. I have deleted & replaced the [node modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi46V.jpg), restarted VS, deleted project.json.lock and still get the error above.

Comment: where is the error screenshot ?

Comment: Please make your question clearer by adding codes/logs/errors.